# Making a property of a JSON file clickeable when need it

Tags: javascript, html, json, object, dom

I got a bunch of objects from a JSON file I received from an API call, I need to render the message property of all the objects and in some of those objects there are hyperlinks within messages.

This is my HTML trying to make the hyperlink within the message clickeable

```
        <div class="quote-text">
            <i class="fas fa-quote-left"></i>
            <span id="message"> <a href="hyperlink"></a></span>
        </div>
```

This is my JS script which I cannot figure how to make it do what I want,
I believe that setting the attribute to the a tag when necessary iterating using for loop or forEach()

```
async function getQuote() {
    loadingSpinner();
    const API = 'https://tronalddump.io/random/quote';

    try {
        const response = await fetch(API);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data.value)
        messageText.innerText = data.value;
        date.innerText = new Date(data.appeared_at).toDateString();
        // authorText.innerText = data._embedded.author[0].name;
        console.log(messageText)
        if (data.value.length > 120) {
            messageText.classList.add('long-quote');
        } else {
            messageText.classList.remove('long-quote');
        }

        completeSpinner();
    } catch (error) {
        // alert(error);
        getQuote();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `href` property in the link.

Example:

```
var link = document.querySelector('.quote-text a'); 

link.href = data.url //Your JSON link property from the api.
```